# Which aircraft has the highest minimum operating temperature?

Tags: aircraft-limitations, temperature

Aircraft often have a minimum operating temperature due to fuel, oil, engine, and other limitations.  Which aircraft has the highest minimum operating temperature, and why?

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

> A Cessna 152 has a minimum operating temp of -5°F while all other aircraft can operate at -6°F or colder, therefore the 152 has the warmest "minimum operating temperature" of all aircraft.
> <sub>Note: numbers made up for an example</sub>

<sup>Clarification based upon comments below</sup>

Comment: Don't you mean lowest minimum operating temperature? Most transports are cert to -40C, or sometimes -45C.

Comment: @JohnK, no I do not.  I would guess some aircraft have water in them and cannot be operated below 0C.  Maybe there are some with higher lower limits?

Comment: Potable water for the Lav system will be loaded with everything running and the interior up to temperature, plus there will be heaters at key points to prevent freezing. Airliners dispatch at temps down to -40 every day in the arctic. Certified minimum operating temps are typically -40C, which means below that, you have to wait for the day to warm up to -40. All the components on the airplane will have been qualified in development to function at -40. In the air, hardware not within the pressure hull may be expected to work down to -60.

Comment: @JohnK Yes, but none of that has anything to do with the water ballast in a sailplane.  The question is broader than airliners.

Comment: Sailplanes don't have fuel, oil ,engine and other limitations lol.

Comment: If you're interested in sailplanes, you may want to [edit] your question to specify that. If there's something else you're after, an edit would certainly help clarify that, too. As it stands, though, I _think_ you're looking for something like "A Cessna 152 has a minimum operating temp of -5°F, therefore it's got the highest minimum operating temp." (_number completely made up_) Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Wildfires need a relatively high temperature to ignite, so firefighting aircrafts have a quite high minimum operating temperature 

Comment: @FreeMan Yes.  It is not sailplane specific.

Comment: I think that would refer more to the _maximum_ operating temp, @sophit. Or, if you're thinking that a fire might only start in the summer when the temp is 95°F/35°C, then that's not the _minimum_ operating temp, that's just the _current_ operating temp.

Comment: @FreeMan obviously I was just joking. But yes, since under 35°C firefighting aircrafts are not operated then that would be the minimum operating temperature 